# How can I remove views from different methods

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is my code to be able to load two different custom views on my main window.  My question is when I hit a button to call my PageTwo method, I am asking it to remove my current view from PageOne and replace it with the new one "text1Title2".  The problem is this will not work unless i restructure my code and place it within one method, which in that case I would need a switch statement and I am not sure how to do this.  Is there a way to remove the view from the other method or release that method when PageTwo method is called?

```
- (void) PageOne
    {
        NSLog(@"FirstPart");

        WelcomeScreenText1* text1ViewController =
        [[WelcomeScreenText1 alloc] initWithNibName:text1Title bundle:nil];
        if (text1ViewController != nil)
        {
            myCurrentViewController = text1ViewController;  
        }

        // embed the current view to our host view
        [myTargetView addSubview: [myCurrentViewController view]];

        // make sure we automatically resize the controller's view to the current window size
        [[myCurrentViewController view] setFrame: [myTargetView bounds]]; 
    }

    - (void) PageTwo
    {

        if ([myCurrentViewController view] != nil)
            [[myCurrentViewController view] removeFromSuperview];   // remove the current view

        if (myCurrentViewController != nil)
            [myCurrentViewController release];

        WelcomeScreenText2* text2ViewController =
        [[WelcomeScreenText2 alloc] initWithNibName:text1Title2 bundle:nil];
        if (text2ViewController != nil)
        {
            myCurrentViewController = text2ViewController;  
        }

        // embed the current view to our host view
        [myTargetView addSubview: [myCurrentViewController view]];

        // make sure we automatically resize the controller's view to the current window size
        [[myCurrentViewController view] setFrame: [myTargetView bounds]];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use UIViews (not UIViewControllers). Add both of them as subviews to your main view and hide them as desired.

```
-(void)switch {
   textView1.hidden = !textView1.hidden;
   textView2.hidden = !textView2.hidden;
}
```